# Core data concurrency type

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data

Can we use only one `NSManagedObjectContext` with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`, without parent `NSManagedObjectContext` with `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`?

Comment: Yes.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  You won't be able to access any `NSManagedObject`s on the main thread.

Comment: I want to have access to core data from any thread

Comment: You can't (reliably) access `NSManagedObject`s from a queue/thread that is different than the one on which it was created.  The only thing that changes between concurrency types is on which queue/thread operations are performed.

Comment: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType will provide infrastructure to achieve core data multithreading implementation. YES you can what you want to do. But your updated entity model will not be in sync with the  UI. If you really want to create single managed object then go with  NSMainQueueConcurrencyType.

Comment: Please provide link to correct multithreading core data implementation